# Tolerance is not satisfied in eigsh function

Tags: sparse-matrix

I am diagonalizing a sparse matrix of size $153600\times 153600$ via `eigsh` function. I did not set the tolerance to specific value, so it would be the default value about $2\times 10^{-16}$. However, if I run the same code 3 times, the difference between eigenvalues are much bigger (about $6 \times 10^{-8}$) than this!
The eigenvalues for 3 trials are shown in the below figure. The real eigenvalue is $10^{-3}$ times the displayed one.

[image]

**Question 1.** Why the tolerance is not satisfied?

**Question 2.** How can I improve tolerance? Does it work if I just set the `tol` value smaller than machine epsilon? (I am worried that numpy module does not support high precision computation than machine epsilon.)

**Question 3.** The documentation for `eigsh` states that the iterative algorithm stops when eigen*value*s reach within the tolerance limit. However, I think eigenvectors have a larger discrepancy for each trials than eigenvalues. Can I control the errors for eigen*vector*s?